# React Native storing images for offline usage

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, react-redux, realm

My React Native app receives data (products) from an API that contains an array of objects, each object has a link for a picture. There is an option to download all the products for offline view (I'm using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) + [realm](https://realm.io/) for that) but the problem is that the pictures itself are not downloaded only the links for them. 
What would be the best way for me to download the pictures so that I can attach them to the corresponding products?

Comment: I will suggest caching the images. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cached-image

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, by a manual way you can download all images as `base64` by using their addresses that comes from the API response. you should use JavaScript to download them, let see a JavaScript base64 downloading:

```js
const imageLink = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

fetch(imageLink)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(data => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      console.log(base64data); // you can store it in your realm
    };
  });
```

After downloading each image store it in your `realm` local database and in usage call it from the `realm`.

There are other ways like using libraries for catching images. like [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image).

Comment: So, do I make a separate async call for each  URL I have and then save the base64 strings as an array in my redux store? 
If I do so, how would I determine which product corresponds to which image?

Comment: @АлександрФомин, Yes the whole approach is exactly like what you write on your comment. but saving each image as base64 data staring at your redux store is not a good idea. I think if you store it in your `realm` database it is a better solution. for binding each product to each downloaded image, save each base64 image align side an id that comes from the own product id, like this: `cachedImages = { 456: base64, 457: base64,  ... }`, when you wanna use it just call `cachedImage[456]` for example.